# Finding numbers inside parentheses

Tags: java

as a part of my project i need to to be able to add the numbers inside these parentheses,i have been working on it for too long but no result, i would appreciated any help

```
String[] s = "1 2 3 ( 4 5 6 ) * 1000 7 8".split("\\s");
```

for example in this case there are 3 numbers

This is what I have so far:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    if ( st.nextToken() != "(" )
        count = count +1 ;
}
if ( st.nextToken() == "(" )
    while (st.nextToken() != ")") {
        count2 = count2 + 1;
    }
System.out.println(count); System.out.println(count2);
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: You have our permission to first try to do this yourself.

Comment: eventually i need to add all these numbers together but the numbers inside of parentheses would be * 1000 in this case

Comment: while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
if ( st.nextToken() != "(" )
count = count +1 ;
}
if ( st.nextToken() == "(" )
while (st.nextToken() != ")"){
count2 = count2 + 1;}
System.out.println(count);
System.out.println(count2);
}

Comment: @Manifiroozi - The code you have posted contains more close braces `}` than open braces `{`, and doesn't include your declaration of `st`. I have pasted you code into your question, please update it with the actual code you are using, including the declaration of `st`

Comment: You really should be using `.equals()` rather than `==` or `!=` to compare strings. `==` will test whether they are _the same object_, but you want to check whether they have the same value.

Comment: How complex are these expressions that you're trying to process? If you're going to need to support things like `"1 2 ( 3 4 ( 5 6 7 ) * ( 8 9 ) 10 ) 11"` then the approach you're taking is going to get very _difficult_ very _quickly_. You might want to learn how to use something like [tag:javacc] or [tag:antlr]

Answer (score 2):

Didn't quite get the use case here. Assuming you are always going to have only one set of paranthesis [ "(" and ")" ], there will never be a paranthesis mismatch and you don't care about the other numbers / digits / operators outside the paranthesis, the easy way to add the numbers between paranthesis would be

```
String mainStr = "1 2 3 ( 4 5 6 ) * 1000 7 8";
String []inside = mainStr.substring(mainStr.indexOf("(")+1, mainStr.indexOf(")")
                  .split("\s");
int sum = 0;
int innerNum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<inside.length;i++) {
    try {
        innerNum = Integer.parseInt(inside[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        innerNum = 0;
    }
    sum = sum + innerNum; 
}
return sum;
```

For multiple sets of paranthesis (which are not nested), we can loop over mainStr to get the next set, and proceed in same manner

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of the parentheses and evalute your string as an equation, you might want to look at the Shunting-yard algorithm.